# Cycles Render just renders a pitch black image

Tags: blender

I'm trying to make a very simple scene ( the one made on this tutorial : https://youtu.be/5tG2wSNCBmE ) and it just renders a pitch black image! I'm new to Blender, so if this is a really dumb, easily fixable issue, I'm sorry. 
Here's the .blend file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzbyknj81q3a92z/House.blend?dl=0

Comment: You can find blender specific help at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your render settings under Film you have changed the exposure to 0.0

Turn that back up to 1.0 for your render to work.

[image: exposure setting]

Comment: This answer only applies to Cycles Render.